# config hex mode to show data byte by byte

Tags: hexl-mode

By default, the hexl mode will show binary data two bytes by two bytes as below:

```
00000000: 0000 0020 6674 7970 6973 6f6d 0000 0200  ... ftypisom....
```

Is it possible to change the style to show data byte by byte? just like below:

```
00000000: 00 00 00 20 66 74 79 70 69 73 6f 6d 00 00 02 00  ... ftypisom....
```

Or any other better hex edit package available for emacs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the user option `hexl-bits` from 16 (2 bytes) to 8 (1 byte):

```el
(setq hexl-bits 8)
```

> Or any other better hex edit package available for emacs?

Maybe https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/nhexl-mode.html

Comment: Thanks, it works fine. I try nhexl also but hexl-bits does't work on nhexl mode.

Comment: @lucky1928 The Commentary of nhexl-mode.el mentions `;;;; Wishlist:  ... ;; - An equivalent to hexl-mode's 'hexl-bits'.`